# Query to get custom data view for Stocks Classifications

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data as shown below where i have the stocks and their class 1 and class2 
Need help in query ideas to achieve the desired result as shown below.I have tried few basic methods ,but could not move forward.Any help would be appreciated.
So the idea is to have the class1 at the top and have all the class2 iterated for all the rows in column 3.

Table Date :

[image]

Expected Data output :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want something like the following, but I am not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for as I don't know where the S and US in the string 'S,3,TESTxxx,US' is comming from:

```
WITH dat AS (SELECT 'INFOTECH' Class1, 'SECOSEEQ' Class2, 'TEST123' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'INFOTECH' Class1, 'SECOSEEQ' Class2, 'TEST124' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'INFOTECH' Class1, 'SECOSEEQ' Class2, 'TEST125' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'INFOTECH' Class1, 'SOSE' Class2, 'TEST126' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'INFOTECH' Class1, 'SOSE' Class2, 'TEST127' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'INFOTECH' Class1, 'SOSE' Class2, 'TEST128' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'INFOTECH' Class1, 'TEHAEQ' Class2, 'TEST129' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'INFOTECH' Class1, 'TEHAEQ' Class2, 'TEST130' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'MATERIAL' Class1, 'ALUMINUM' Class2, 'TEST131' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'MATERIAL' Class1, 'ALUMINUM' Class2, 'TEST132' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'MATERIAL' Class1, 'CHEMICAL' Class2, 'TEST133' Asset FROM dual
              UNION ALL
             SELECT 'MATERIAL' Class1, 'CHEMICAL' Class2, 'TEST134' Asset FROM dual)
SELECT CASE WHEN class2 IS NULL 
            THEN '1,'||class1
            WHEN asset IS NULL 
            THEN '2,'||class2
            ELSE 'S,3,'||asset||',US'
       END  
  FROM dat
 GROUP BY class1, ROLLUP(class2,asset)
 ORDER BY class1, class2 nulls first, asset nulls first
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Radagast81 for your quick response,i think this will help me to do start my development.I will post f i face any hurdles ,but that was quick from you.

Comment: The query has helped me to embed the code into development with few changes.I also wanted to check if this can be applied if there are 6 classes (class1 to class 6).What would be key things to take into account to make it work for any classes.

Comment: I general you can use the query for any number of "classes" you just have to add the new columns in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`clauses. But if you are the one who designes the database structure (TABLES etc.) you might want to change the table structure to a tree structure. Give every entity an ID and self join the table with a new column "PARENT_CLASS_ID". See here for additional information about querying such data: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52318

Comment: We are only involved in generating reports,unfortunately the database structure is not in our control.Thanks for clarifying though.